# Why does my EF Core query return the list that does not match results in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Nub struggle with SQL query in EF Core. I have a DBSet that I am trying to populate with a SQL query. I don't know if the query is important but here it is:

```sql
select top 10
    2 as docstorageid, 
    d.ID as originaldocid,
    df.id as originalfileid, 
    c.id as custid,
    u.id as userid,
    -1 as id, 
    df.Page as PageId, 
    df.FileName as FilePath  
from 
    documents d 
inner join 
    DocumentFiles df on df.Documents_ID = d.id
inner join 
    users u on u.login_id = d.UploadedBy_User_ID
inner join 
    customers c on c.id = u.Customers_ID
where 
    df.FileTypes_ID = 2 
    and substring (df.FileName, 1, 4) = 'arti'
    and df.id not in (select originalfileid 
                      from documenttemplatefiles)
order by 
    d.id desc
```

It executes just fine in SQL Server Management Studio, returning 10 unique rows.

My EF Core code is:

```cs
int count =10;

try
{
    List <DocTemplateFile> rval = _context.DocumentTemplateFiles.FromSql(
        $@"select distinct
            2 as docstorageid, 
            d.ID as originaldocid,
            df.id as originalfileid, 
            c.id as custid,
            u.id as userid,
            -1 as id, 
            df.Page as PageId, 
            df.FileName as FilePath
        from documents d
        inner join DocumentFiles df on df.Documents_ID = d.id
        inner join users u on u.login_id = d.UploadedBy_User_ID
        inner join customers c on c.id = u.Customers_ID
        where df.FileTypes_ID = 2 and substring(df.FileName, 1,4) = 'arti'
            and df.id not in (select originalfileid from documenttemplatefiles)"
    )
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Id)
    .Take(count)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

    return rval;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return new List<DocTemplateFile>();
}
```

There are two problems:

1. The resulting list contains 10 records of the same data
2. The first element in this list does not match what SQL returns in SQL Server Management Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your sql already has a distinct?

Comment: There's no `distinct` in the first query. That's a major difference. Even though it's not necessary (as you explain below) it's a confusing element in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the class DocTemplateFile has to have unique key defined. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Your EF code is ordering by the identity ID (`b => b.Id`, which is `-1` because of `-1 as id` in your query), whereas your query is ordering by `originaldocid` (`d.id`). Not sure if that's the problem but it's the first thing I noticed.

Comment: Thank you, RobIII. The sort is fixed, after the fix applied (.OrderByDescending( b => b.OriginalDocId )) EF query still returns the same "first" row..

Comment: @MichaelEstrinOne Another thing I notice is you're doing `distinct` in your query AND in Linq. I suggest you let the database take care of it and remove the `Distinct()` call.  Another bad habit is sweeping exceptions under the mat and simply returning an empty list. This may hide potential errors and get your application in an undefined state (maybe not this particular instance, but generally).

Comment: I just noticed: the 'original' query doesn't even have a distinct? Why have it twice in your C# code then?

Comment: the explanation for distinct being omitted in the sql query is simple -  I did not need to have it, the query returns correct data. I started to add Distinct anywhere I can in C# because the results came back identical in every element of the list. Thank you for noticing that, I'll remove it and start over, coming back to the starting point of the problem.